# Twilio Flex UI - WebRTC/ORTC deploy error

Tags: reactjs, twilio, twilio-flex

I am building a custom [Twilio Flex](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/flex-overview-ui-programmability) plugin using [this repo](https://github.com/twilio/flex-ui-sample) as the starting point. When I build and deploy the built project, I get the error:

> Failed to initialize Flex: twilio.js 1.3+ SDKs require WebRTC/ORTC browser support. For more information, see https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/twilio-js. If you have any questions about this announcement, please contact Twilio Support at .

The weird thing is the `twilio-client` is not ever used directly in this app. I even tried to add it as a dependency with the most updated stable version but still getting the same error. I'm on Google Chrome version 75.0.3770.80. It runs just fine locally while developing. But, as soon as the project is built with `react-scripts build`, it throws the error above. Anyone dealt with this before??

Comment: Twilio Client is a part of Flex overall, but it is weird you're seeing this error. I just cloned and built the `flex-ui-sample` project with no issues, can you share what you've changed in the project? Have you added more dependencies? Removed any? Changed or added code?

Comment: One other thing, we recommend using [flex-plugin-builder](https://github.com/twilio/flex-plugin-builder/) to build your own Flex plugin. Take a look at that project to see if it might help too.

Comment: I needed more control over the base app structure than the flex plugin builder gave me.

Comment: Fair enough, can you answer my other questions to give me a bit more insight about what might be causing this?

Comment: I can build my project just fine. That part succeeds. I only see the error when I try to visit the page it is served on. I have added some minor dependencies such as reactstrap, lodash, moment, etc. But, the big dependencies that I've added are for the apollo graphql client and then stuff for an additional redux store.

Comment: Was there a point at which the project built and worked for you?

Comment: This is the first time that I am deploying the static files. I've just been developing locally for the last few weeks. And everything has worked fine on local host

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on then, I'm afraid. I can build and run the base project from flex-ui-sample with no issue. So whatever is causing this appears to be between when you cloned the sample and now. Perhaps you can run back through your commits to try to pinpoint the time it stopped working and we can inspect what had changed at that point?